# HTML table - remove cellspacing/border from a particular cell

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table with 3 columns. I'd like to remove the border/cellspacing between the first and second columns, and make it appear like one column.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o8x3ego0/1/

HTML

```
<table id="holdingsDistributionTable" class="table table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Currency</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="currencyHolder greenCurrencyHolder">
        <div class="currency greenCurrency">
          AED
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        UA Emirates Dirham
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b>345</b>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="currencyHolder blueCurrencyHolder">
        <div class="currency blueCurrency">
          ARS
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        Argentine Peso
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>45345</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

In the above example, I'd like to remove the spacing between the 1st and 2nd columns in the data rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the border from the entire table by:

```
table {  
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Then to add borders to the rows, table headers and the last table cells (or whatever table cells necessary by using `:nth-child`):

```
tr, th, td:last-child  {
  border: 1px solid black;        /* changed to black to be more noticeable */
}
```

Then remove padding from the table header and table cells:

```
th, td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6afxs9sw/).

Answer (score 0):

edit: it was col and not row, so i believe this is more like this : https://jsfiddle.net/o8x3ego0/6/ *(same method, but padding to draw the hole in between th )*
you can use

> `border-collapse` to remove `cellspacing` and to allow style  `tr` `borders`
>
> a `line-height` to `th` instead `padding`
>
> draw a `transparent` `border` at `bottom` of `th` (`padding` works too)
>
> and erase bg color with `background-clip` to mimic the `border-spacing` only where you want to

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
/* demo */

tr:nth-child(1) th {
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  background-clip: content-box
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
/* end */

.table {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.table-responsive {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.currencyHolder {
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}
.currency {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.greenCurrencyHolder {
  background-color: green;
  border-color: darkgreen;
}
.greenCurrency {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
.blueCurrencyHolder {
  background-color: azure;
  border-color: cadetblue;
}
.blueCurrency {
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
#holdingsDistributionTable {
  display: table;
  /*width: 100% !important;*/
}
#holdingsDistributionTable th {
  background-color: #F4F5F6;
  color: #AAABAE;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  /* instead vertical  padding */
  width: 25%;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#holdingsDistributionTable th:last-child,
#holdingsDistributionTable td:last-child {
  background-color: #DFE1E3;
  color: #A19D9E;
}
#holdingsDistributionTable td:last-child {
  background-color: #DFE1E3;
  color: black;
}
#holdingsDistributionTable th,
#holdingsDistributionTable td {
  min-height: 15px;
  background-color: #F4F5F6;
}
```

```html
<table id="holdingsDistributionTable" class="table table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Currency</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="currencyHolder greenCurrencyHolder">
        <div class="currency greenCurrency">
          AED
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        UA Emirates Dirham
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b>345</b>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="currencyHolder blueCurrencyHolder">
        <div class="currency blueCurrency">
          ARS
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        Argentine Peso
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>45345</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to make your table only two columns in the first place and do not use `colspan="2"` then make the stylized currency abbreviation line up with the currency name by setting the two div in each column inline block items using `display: inline-block;` in your CSS

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f30tujzn/

this solution is not only easier then removing part of your border but will render faster, and respond better on smaller devices.